# Bing map on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, xmlreader

How can i display a list of positions (from a xml document:using xml reading) in a Bing map with WP7? The idea is similar to Foursquare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft wrote a good throughout [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447) on the subject, that also explains how to use databinding, so you can do proper code and view seperation.

Comment: @ClausJergensen  Tutorial link now broken

Answer (score 0):

It all relies on instances of [Pushpin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.pushpin%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that are placed on a map layer. You can see a short working sample [here](http://mws580.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/add-map-and-points-to-windows-phone-7/).

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial linked by Claus nicely points out how you can use Pushpins on a BingMapsControl. If you take out the essence of the tutorial this is the piece of code you want to use. All you need is a collection of items with at least a Location attribute. If you want your Pushpin to have a label you can also add a Name attribute.

You can databind the collection of items to your mapcontrol by adding this piece of code within your BingMapsControl.

```
        <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
            <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pushpin Content="{Binding Name}" Location="{Binding Location}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl>
```

If you need any more explanation please refer to the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447) mentioned by Claus